# Specifying optional arguments when initializing chrome webdriver causes status code 1

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using selenium to test some features of a website and I can't figure out why specifying optional arguments causes it to fail.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=driver_dir,
    service=Service(driver_dir, log_path=self.crawl_dir)
)
```

I have also tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=driver_dir,
    service_log_path=log_dir
)
```

Both of these examples cause the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
...
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 110, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Users\user\Desktop\Programs\JQuery_Testing\Crabby_Crawler\lib\..\driver\chromedriver.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

When I don't specify any optional arguments it works fine:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=driver_dir
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: the constructor is getting confused... it doesn't expect you to have (String, Service)... see here: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/Overload_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriver__ctor.htm  (basically just remove executable_path and should work)

Comment: @pcalkins removing the line `executable_path=driver_dir` and leaving the service parameter still gives me the same failed output, am I missing something?

Comment: Seems like you'll want to pass service and chromeoptions.... but if it's working with just executable path, remove the service part.  (don't know python myself, but I think it's service=..., options= then chrome options object?)